# Update Custom Picklist Values Translations via MetadataService

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist, translation, mdapi

I have a piece of code that allows me to update custom picklist field values:

```
public static TM_EComUtils.genericResponse addPicklistValuesViaMetadata(String fieldAPI, String sObjectAPI, List<String> newPicklistValues){
    MetadataService.SaveResult result;
    MetadataService.CustomField pckField;
    MetadataService.CustomValue newValue;
    TM_EComUtils.genericResponse GenericResponse; //wrapper for response

    try{
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort(); 
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        //Get custom picklist field
        pckField = (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', new List<String>{ (sObjectAPI + '.' + fieldAPI) }).getRecords()[0];

        //Add new picklist values
        for(String value : newPicklistValues){
            newValue = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
            newValue.fullName = value;
            newValue.default_x = false;  
            pckField.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value.add(newValue);
        }
        
        //Update
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){ result = service.updateMetadata( new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{pckField})[0]; }
        else{ 
            result = new MetadataService.SaveResult();
            result.success = true;
        }

        //Success
        if(result.success){ return new TM_EComUtils.genericResponse(true); }

        //Error
        else if(result.success && result.errors != null && !result.errors.isEmpty()){
            TM_EComUtils.storeError(result.errors[0].message, '01', null, TM_EComUtils.class.getName(), 'addPicklistValuesViaMetadata', null);    
            GenericResponse = new TM_EComUtils.genericResponse(result.errors[0].message, '01');
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        TM_EComUtils.storeError(null, '02', exc, TM_EComUtils.class.getName(), 'addPicklistValuesViaMetadata', null);   
        GenericResponse = new TM_EComUtils.genericResponse(exc.getMessage(), '02');
    }
    
    return GenericResponse;
        
}
```

And it's working fine but now I need a way to also update this new values translations. Is this possible via `MetadataService`? Cause I'm not finding anything useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can always take a look at the [MetadataService.cls](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) to see what types are called out there. Anything in there is useable to be read if it extends Metadata.

In this case, they have `CustomObjectTranslation` which contains a `CustomFieldTranslation` which then contains the `PicklistValueTranslation` you seek.

Read current object translations by passing in object name + language code as noted in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm). Example below for an object named "Custom_Object__c" and Japanese language translations.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();

MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation  objectTranslation = (MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation ) service.readMetadata('CustomObjectTranslation',new String[]{'Custom_Object__c-ja'}).getRecords()[0];
```

Loop through until you get to the `PicklistValueTranslation` to make updates

```
for(MetadataService.CustomFieldTranslation customFieldTranslation : objectTranslation.fields){
    if(customFieldTranslation.picklistValues != null){
        for(MetadataService.PicklistValueTranslation picklistValueTranslation : customFieldTranslation.picklistValues){
            //update the translation field to be the value you're seeking
            System.debug(picklistValueTranslation.masterLabel);
            picklistValueTranslation.translation = 'New Value';
        }
    }
}
```

You can then pass the same custom object translation to the MetadataService to update with the new translations you changed above for a given language

```
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[] { objectTranslation });
```